# Extract data from notification object android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

When building a notification in android, we provide a PendingIntent which contains an Intent object which also contains some data passed as extras.

```
// here we create the Intent and we add the extra model data to it
val notificationIntentActivity =
            notificationService.getActivityIntent(context)
notificationIntentActivity.putExtra(ARG_MODEL, myModel)


// here we create the PendingIntent which contains the notificationIntentActivity
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                notificationIntentActivity,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )


// here we build the notification where we pass the pendingIntent
val mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context,
            channelId
        )
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
mBuilder.build()
```

So now lets say that the user opens the application and i want to check the following

1. If there is any available active notification about my app
2. If there is any, then i want to extract the "ARG_MODEL" data from it

```
override fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()

   val nm = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
   val mNotification = nm.activeNotifications.first().notification
   // here how can i get the Intent Model data ("myModel") from the notification object??   

}
```